# What has trump accomplished in his first term?

Tags: donald-trump

[Source](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/06/17/us/politics/trump-2020-election.html)

> In a statement, a White House spokeswoman, Alyssa Farah, said, “The
> president is fully committed to serving a second term and building on
> and adding to his first-term accomplishments for the American people.”

Without starting a flame war, what are those accomplishments?

Comment: Interesting question, but so many times asked...

Comment: Maybe would be worth having a meta discussion on "so far"-questions, as the answers to them slightly change as time goes on, but the answers on other questions aren't updated...

Comment: @miep, brilliant idea, done: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4461/handling-questions-that-are-dynamic-and-change-over-time

Comment: I consider that opinion based - i.e. how you define accomplishments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citing [Politifact's Trump-o-meter](https://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/promises/trumpometer/), President Trump fulfilled 19 of his 102 campaign promises, compromised on 11, and 27 are in the works.

Promises that he kept include:

- He has renegotiated NAFTA with Canada and Mexico.
- He has reversed an Obama-era executive order requiring Social Security benefits with mental illness to have this reflected in background checks when they purchase firearms.
- He has accelerated funding of NATO by other member countries (while some of this increase was there before, it has accelerated).
- He has limited the number of refugees to the United States to 30,000 per year.
- He has raised tariffs on goods from various other countries, notably China.

Comment: But (as mentioned in the comments) whether or not these are accomplishments or failures really depends on a) one's personal opinions; and b) long-term results.  E.g. raising tariffs is a fact.  Whether this should be seen as an accomplishment or not depends on for instance your committment to free market economics, and the effects on the economy for years & decades.

Comment: For this question, I'm defining an "accomplishment" as achieving something that he intended to achieve.  I'm not going to opine on whether they are positive or negative.